# Dev tools: copy url with parameters?

Tags: javascript, firebug

For many many years I used Firebug, and it had a very handy feature, where you could click on an ajax request, and regardless of whether it was a GET or a POST etc, it would give you an option to 'Copy url with parameters' which would then create a GET url.

None of today's dev tools seem to have this feature - I basically have to compile the url manually by copying the base url, then copying the parameters and fiddling with the text to make it a url. This is really annoying.

Does anybody know of a way around this, or some plugin etc which would help?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your use case to copy POST requests as GET requests?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome dev tools

Debugger -> Network -> XHR -> left-click on request -> view source for response / request / paramteres / form data/

It is very easy and simple.

Debugger -> Network -> XHR -> right-click on request -> Copy

[image]

Comment: Thanks Colin, but this just copies the URL. If there are GET parameters in the URL they're included, however, if it was a POST, then you don't get the parameters. This is my issue.

Comment: You can copy entire request body.  So it basically takes two actions, one to copy URL and another to copy body.

Comment: It takes a few actions - one to copy the URL, one to copy the parametes, then another to put a '?' after the url, and add = and & in between the copied parameters. It is possible, but it is a mission for the frequency I would like to do this. I am just not sure why they'd not implement such basic functionality

Comment: So you want to convert body from POST request to url params GET request. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delayed response! I've given up on this, I just have to change the POST to a GET temporarily while I am debugging certain code. Not ideal, but it works.